# Trigger onChange for Semantic UI dropdown

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

Simply put, I would like to be able to trigger the onChange function in the dropdown for semantic ui.

```
$(".ui.dropdown").dropdown({onChange:function(value,text){console.log("a");}});
```

See a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/0mLLscoq/

I want to trigger the onchange without clicking the dropdown and closing it. Simply programmatically forcing a trigger.

Comment: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1351

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to do it with the API, but one possible hack is to assign a `data-value` to each item and then manually trigger the click for that item:

```
//HTML
<div class="ui dropdown">
    <div class="text">Select</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="Edit">Edit</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="Remove">Remove</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="Hide">Hide</div>
    </div>
</div>

//JS
$(".ui.dropdown").dropdown({onChange:function(value,text){console.log("a");}})
                 .find("[data-value='Hide']").trigger("click");
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0mLLscoq/1/)**

---

**Update (Mar 11th 2016):**

As @Süha mentions in the comments there is a [dropdown behavior](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#behavior) that allows you to change the value:

```
// Will change value and update UI
$('.dropdown').dropdown('set selected', 'Hide');

// Will only change value
$('.dropdown').dropdown('set value', 'Hide');
```

But neither of these will trigger the `onchange` event.

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0mLLscoq/12/)**

Comment: I assume there should be a way to grab the onChange function.... I do like your hack, but I don't consider it yet a proper solution as it is a hack. I do really like it though, and if I use it I will try to remember to mark your solution as correct.

Comment: for newcomers, there is a "set value" behavior for dropdown in semantic-ui